# CMake works on Mac, but not Linux?

Tags: c, linux, compilation, cmake, cross-platform

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.7)
project (Test)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(PortAudio REQUIRED)
find_package(LibSndFile REQUIRED)

include_directories(src/audio src/web)
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY} ${PORTAUDIO_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c)

add_executable(Test ${sources})
target_link_libraries(Test ${LIBS})
```

Here is what my folder structure looks like:

```
Test/
├── .gitignore
├── README
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src/
│   ├── audio/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── web/
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── build/
└── cmake/
    ├── FindLibSndFile.cmake
    └── FindPortaudio.cmake
```

When I go to compile my program on a Mac, I go into the `build/` directory and run `cmake ..`, to which the program generates:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/libcurl.dylib (found version "7.30.0") 
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- checking for module 'portaudio-2.0'
--   found portaudio-2.0, version 19
-- Found LibSndFile: /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.dylib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: Development/Test/build
```

Everything runs fine and dandy.  But when I copy the source over to my Raspberry Pi and repeat the above steps, it spits this out at me:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so (found version "7.26.0") 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPortAudio.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "PortAudio", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PortAudio" with
  any of the following names:

    PortAudioConfig.cmake
    portaudio-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PortAudio" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PortAudio_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PortAudio" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm not too sure why it isn't working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macs are case insensitive while other operating systems are generally case sensitive.  To solve this problem, either change the file name of `FindPortaudio.cmake` --> `FindPortAudio.cmake` (notice the capital `A` in audio).  Or in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, change the `A` in audio to a lowercase character.  i.e., change

```
find_package(PortAudio REQUIRED)
```

to

```
find_package(Portaudio REQUIRED)
```

Comment: I thought that maybe it had to do with the path to the `.cmake` files, the case of the letter being the problem surprised me. It worked though, thanks!